# Caption-package: caption* does not work?

Tags: numbering, captions, sv-classes

I have a chapter in which I need for tables and figures to exceptionally not be numbered. Caption package apparently provides for this by using \caption*{title} . However, this does not seem to work for me. Any idea why?

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\graphicspath{{Figures/}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
\toprule
Title of Table \\ \midrule
\end{tabular}
\caption*{Captiontext}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This is the result: [image]

Comment: I don't think `caption` is compatible with `svmono`.

Comment: If not, is there any other option for the numbering of tables and figures to disappear?

Comment: Why don't you simply write the text without the caption command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running LaTeX on your document produces the following warning:

```
Package caption Warning: \caption will not be redefined since it's already
(caption)                redefined by a document class or package which is
(caption)                unknown to the caption package.
```

This means you can't use `caption` with the `svmono` class.

In your case, just adding the text will do.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\graphicspath{{Figures/}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
\toprule
Title of Table \\ \midrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{\protect\lipsum*[2]}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp]
\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
\toprule
Title of Table \\ \midrule
\end{tabular}

\vspace{\tabcapgap}

\lipsum[2]

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In principle, this appears to work. Thanks! However, what does the \vspace{\abovecaptionskip} do? I am asking, as now the margin between the figure and the text is too wide and I need to manually reduce it only for this single figure. Any idea as to how?

Comment: @kuuhkuuh It's the standard space preceding a caption.

Comment: It appears, the the space following the figure/table and preceding the text is by default too wide (i.e. wider than for a caption) and I need to further reduce it to make the text look like a caption. Do you have a suggestion for that?

Comment: @kuuhkuuh It is `\tabcapgap`; I changed the example to show that the spacing is the same in both cases.

Comment: Strange, it does not work for me. Is there a different way to change the margin once?

Comment: @kuuhkuuh In the example above, you can see that the text behaves exactly as captions do.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue also in my language Greek, namely the was a warning for greeknumericals and the \caption* did not work. In order to avoid these conflict issues within the language you are writing (sumovo) I think you can set this new command, in the preamble:

\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\arabic{subfigure}}

and then use caption*{}.

See also this [link](http://www.peteryu.ca/tutorials/publishing/latex_captions) for further details

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).